# Submit the form but don't reload the page. Webmatrix razor

Tags: forms, razor, webmatrix

I need to figure out a way to submit my form but do not reload the page so that my page doesn't scroll to top again. Is there a way?

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
<button type="submit">Click</button>
</form>

if(Ispost){
Do something but do not reload the page. PS this is razor page.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but it's as much to do with the client-side code as it is to do with your server-side parts.

Using a library like jQuery will simplify things, and you can `$.serialize()` (https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function to turn the data in your form into a format the the `$.post()` (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) function can then send to your WebMatrix endpoint.

Off the top of my head, some JS/JQ code like this should do the trick:

```
var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
$.post(url, data, function () {
    // tell the user it succeeded
}).fail(function () {
    // tell the user it failed
});
```

The above assumes that your form has an action specified with the URL you want to post the data to, and the serialize() will make sure any fields in the form are passed through to the endpoint.

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" action="/my-end-point">
<input type="text" name="someval" id="someval" />
<button type="submit">Click</button>
</form>
```